# R: use of "where" to select rows by matching an element from a list

Tags: r, loops, plot, where-clause

I'm attempting to use the "where" function in R within a loop to pick out a certain row from two datasets based on a matching element, and then make a scatterplot of the two. They code sample below provides the row names of the two dataframes and the loop. Each dataframe contains more counties than are listed in "mycounties".

I have used the "where" function in a loop exactly like this before, but this time R is returning the error message that "where" doesn't exist?  I know "where" exists!  My question is, how do I make R recognize this "where" structure, or is there a better way to pick out the rows I want to plot?

```
 > names(dts)
 [1] "county"  "Freq125" "Freq126" "Freq127" "Freq128" "Freq129" "Freq130" "Freq131" "Freq132" "Freq133" "Freq134" "Freq135" "Freq136" "Freq137"
[15] "Freq138" "Freq139" "Freq140" "Freq141" "Freq142" "Freq143" "Freq144" "Freq145" "Freq146" "Freq147" "Freq148" "Freq149" "Freq150" "Freq151"
[29] "Freq152" "Freq153" "Freq154" "Freq155" "Freq156" "Freq157" "Freq158" "Freq159" "Freq160" "Freq161" "Freq162" "Freq163" "Freq164" "Freq165"
[43] "Freq166" "Freq167" "Freq168" "Freq169" "Freq170" "Freq171"

> names(pm)
 [1] "county" "pm125m" "pm126m" "pm127m" "pm128m" "pm129m" "pm130m" "pm131m" "pm132m" "pm133m" "pm134m" "pm135m" "pm136m" "pm137m" "pm138m"
[16] "pm139m" "pm140m" "pm141m" "pm142m" "pm143m" "pm144m" "pm145m" "pm146m" "pm147m" "pm148m" "pm149m" "pm150m" "pm151m" "pm152m" "pm153m"
[31] "pm154m" "pm155m" "pm156m" "pm157m" "pm158m" "pm159m" "pm160m" "pm161m" "pm162m" "pm163m" "pm164m" "pm165m" "pm166m" "pm167m" "pm168m"
[46] "pm169m" "pm170m" "pm171m"
> 
> mycounties = c("beaufort", "bertie", "bladen", "camden", "carteret", "chowan", "craven", 
+   "cumberland", "currituck", "dare", "duplin", "gates", "greene", "harnett", "hyde",
+   "jones", "lenoir", "new hanover", "onslow", "pamlico", "pasquotank", "pender", "perquimans", "pitt", "robeson", "sampson", "tyrrell", "washington")
> 
> LOOP
> for (i in 1:length(mycounties)) {
+ x = pm[where(pm$county == mycounties[i]),2:48]
+ y = dt[where(dts$county == mycounties[i]),2:48 ]
+ plot( x, y, main=paste("HYSPLIT & ED Visits", counties[i], sep=""),
+  xlab="HYSPLIT", ylab="ED Visits", pch=19)
+ } 
Error in `[.data.frame`(pm, where(pm$county == mycounties[i]), 2:48) : 
  could not find function "where"
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Like Jeff and the comments have said, there is no where function.  `which` is the R version.

However, in this example you don't need `which` at all:

```
x <- pm[pm$county == mycounties[i], 2:48]
y <- dt[dt$county == mycounties[i], 2:48]
```

Also in your example `if` statement:

```
if (mat$county[i] %in% dt5$county)) {
    mat[i,2:58] = dt5[dt5$county == mat$county[i], 2:58]
}
```

That is assuming your `dt5$county` has only one matching county for each `mat$county[i]`.  Otherwise you'll get an error.

Answer (score 6):

Are you trying to refer to the `which()` function?

Comment: No, "where".  Here is a sample of a line I have run before in a similar loop that worked just fine:  if (mat$county[i] %in% list(dt5$county)) {mat[i,2:58] = dt5[where(mat$county[i] == dt5$county), 2:58]}

Comment: When you ran that line, either someone must have defined the "where" function elsewhere, or the conditional never executed (that is, `(mat$county[i] %in% list(dt5$county))` was never true. `where` is certainly not a built in function in R. `which` is.

Comment: Interesting!  So that previous loop I used must have created incorrect results... I will have to go back and cross check it.  Thank you!  Sooooo is it possible to use "which" in this case?  I will try ?which

Comment: Yes. It looks like `which` would meet your needs. I'm not familiar with a `where` function.

Comment: In fact, I am almost certain that the conditional you give is never true. I assume `mat` is a matrix and `dt5` a dataframe. In that case, you would mean to do `mat$county[i] %in% dt5$county`, not `(mat$county[i] %in% list(dt5$county))`, which is never true.